# How to auto login when accessToken expired with @azure/msal-browser

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an application where authorization happens through **@azure/msal-browser**

And at the moment it works for me like this: when the session time ends, the **expired** field appears and a modal window is shown according to this condition.
The modal window has two buttons, logout and login, when you click on the login button, you are redirected to the msal login page

But now I want to make sure that the modal window is not shown, but a token request is made, since the user was already in the system earlier and there was no need to go to the login page and enter data

implemented the call to acquireTokenSilent

But how can I do everything further, please tell me

```
    requestAccessToken = (homeAccountId?: string) => {
        const request: SilentRequest = tokenRequest;
        const id = homeAccountId || this.currentAccountId;
        const account = this.instance.getAccountByHomeId(id as string);
        request.account = account || undefined;
        return this.instance
          .acquireTokenSilent(request)
          .then((response: any) => {
            if (!response.accessToken || response.accessToken === '') {
              throw new InteractionRequiredAuthError();
            } else {
              return response.accessToken;
            }
          })
          .catch(this.handleTokenError);
      };
```

```
     <DialogSessionExpired
                isOpen={currentAccount?.expired}
                onLogin={signIn}
                onLogout={signOut}
        />
```

```
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [...apiConfig.b2cScopes],
  prompt: 'select_account',
};
export const tokenRequest = {
  scopes: [...apiConfig.b2cScopes],
  forceRefresh: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `acquireTokenSilent` method tries to fetch the token from the local cache and tries to refresh it silently using an iframe if expired, by default.

But if your scenario requires an interactive login instead, you could simply check for that error and call the `acquireTokenPopup` method in the catch handler like illustrated [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md#popup).

Here is the same for reference

```js
var request = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"],
};

msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(tokenResponse => {
    // Do something with the tokenResponse
}).catch(async (error) => {
    if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
        return msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(request);
    }

    // handle other errors
})
```